# How to pass javascript variable value to php variable using ajax to store in session in codeighter

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I am working in codeighther and want to pass my javascript variable value to php so that I can store it in session and then store to database.

Following is what I have tried so far.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <button id="detect-button">Detect Device</button>
</div>

<script>
    $('#detect-button').ready(function() {

        var detector = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent)
        var test = document.write("Mobile: " + detector.mobile());

        //document.write( "Phone: " + detector.phone());
        //document.write( "Tablet: " + detector.tablet());
        // document.write( "OS: " + detector.os());
        // document.write( "userAgent: " + detector.userAgent());


    });

    $.ajax({
                type: 'Post',
                url: '<?php echo  $base_url ?>Home/index',
                data: ({
                    value: +detector.mobile()
                }),
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#results').html(data);
                }
</script>

<p id="results"> </p>
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working on your end? What is supposed to happen?

Comment: actually i want to get the value which i has stored in test and want to store in php variable so that i can store it into database

Comment: Can you post the PHP code as well?

Comment: i am not able to get the value , in php

Comment: php code in nothing just a div with id results <div id = results></div

Comment: Must be something more if you want to get and store the variable right?

Comment: i don't know can u please help me to fetch the value

Answer (score 0):

you can pass you test varibale data like,

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<?php echo  $base_url ?>Home/index',
                data: {field1 : test},
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#results').html(data);
  }
```

And you can fetch data in PHP like $_POST['field1']

For more details, please visit http://thisinterestsme.com/simple-ajax-request-example-jquery-php/

I would recommend you to make use of the $.post or $.get syntax of jQuery for simple cases.

Comment: Undefined index: field

Comment: it is field1, try to fetch value like $_POST['field1'] in your php script

Answer (score 0):

Define detector as a global variable. Its current scope is restricting its use

Comment: $.ajax({

                        url: '<?php echo $base_link ?>Home/index',
                        data : ({field : "mokshesh"}),
                        success: function (fff) {
                            alert(fff);
                        }

                    });
                });

Comment: i cam getting alert like ,

Comment: Because what is being returned is the DOM. Which, you know, starts off with ::: doctype html and list of meta tags

Comment: My friend: What is it that you are trying to do? It will probably be much faster to do that for you than try and figure out your kryptic nuances between your kindered lamenting :)